# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException onActivityResult

Tags: android, kotlin

Google Console reports error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` at `onActivityResult`

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue

parameter `data` of `onActivityResult` method can be `null` so we should make it optional

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    //
}
```

It was automatically converted wrongly this from Java to Kotlin in Android Studio